# Terraform : removal of identity block does not remove identity assigned from resource azure logic app

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, azure-logic-app-standard

I have this in my main.tf and

```
dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identity == [] ? [] : [1]
    content {
      type         = lookup(var.identity, "type", null)
      #identity_ids = lookup(var.identity, "identity_ids", null)
    }
}
```

I have defined variable as below.

```
variable "identity" {
  description = "creates the identity for Logic App."
  type    = any
  default = []
}
```

Removing identity block from input does not remove assigned identity. Terraform does not detect the change. Can some1 help ?

Also Logic App standard only supports SystemAssigned but doc says something else :
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard

Comment: Can you provide full context of your code? Also `lookup` is for maps, but your variable is a list.

Comment: So I created a logic app standard resource with SystemAssigned identity and now I want to remove it. 

I tried with default value as null as well but no change.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some type confusion in your configuration here, but Terraform isn't able to detect and report it because you didn't give a specific type constraint for your variable.

Specifically, it's not clear whether you intended `var.identity` to be a list of objects or a single object. You declared the default as `[]`, suggesting you meant a list, but the content of the `dynamic "identity"` block treats `var.identity` as if it's just a single object.

I'm going to write this out both ways, so you can choose which one meets your actual requirement.

---

For a list of "identities" with one `identity` block each:

```
variable "identities" {
  type = list(object({
    type         = string
    identity_ids = set(string)
  }))
  default = []
}

resource "example" "example" {
  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identities
    content {
      type         = each.value.type
      identity_ids = each.value.identity_ids
    }
  }
}
```

---

For a single "identity" object that is optional:

```
variable "identities" {
  type = object({
    type         = string
    identity_ids = set(string)
  })
  default = null
}


resource "example" "example" {
  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identities[*]
    content {
      type         = each.value.type
      identity_ids = each.value.identity_ids
    }
  }
}
```

In this second example, notice that:

- The type constraint for `variable "identities"` is now just for an object type directly, without the `list(...)` from the first example.
- The default value for that variable is now `null`, which is the typical way to represent the absence of a single value.
- The `dynamic "identity"` block's `for_each` expression uses [the `[*]` operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html), called the "splat operator", which has [a special behavior](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#single-values-as-lists) where it'll convert a null value into an empty list and a *non-null* value into a single-element list, thus producing a suitable collection value for the `for_each` argument.

---

I would recommend always writing [type constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html) for your input variables, because then Terraform can give you better feedback in situations like yours where you were not consistent in the types you were using. If you use `any` in a type constraint then Terraform will have less insight into what you are intending and so its error messages will typically be less specific and possibly even misleading, if it makes an incorrect assumption about what your goals were.